# How to add CFLAGS to my Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm using LEDE SDK and trying to compile latest reaver from git, but cant add `CFLAGS="-O0 -g3"` to my Makefile ? Do I need to just add them to

```
CONFIGURE_ARGS += --enable-savetocurrent
```

or what ? Here is my Makefile

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2012-2015 OpenWrt.org
# Copyright (C) 2017 Yousong Zhou
#
# This is free software, licensed under the GNU General Public License v2.
# See /LICENSE for more information.
#

include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=reaver
PKG_VERSION:=1.6.3
PKG_RELEASE:=2
PKG_MAINTAINER:=Yousong Zhou <yszhou4tech@gmail.com>

PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION).tar.xz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x/releases/download/v$(PKG_VERSION)
PKG_HASH:=191f785f53030e4803260ada1a29ca4b42c848d56f6f3982e320d03b6117aaf2

PKG_LICENSE:=GPL-2.0
PKG_LICENSE_FILES:=docs/LICENSE

PKG_USE_MIPS16:=0
PKG_AUTOMAKE_PATHS:=src
PKG_FIXUP:=autoreconf

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
CONFIGURE_PATH:=src
MAKE_PATH:=src

CONFIGURE_ARGS += --enable-savetocurrent

define Package/reaver
  SECTION:=net
  CATEGORY:=Network
  SUBMENU:=wireless
  TITLE:=Efficient brute force attack against Wifi Protected Setup
  URL:=https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x
  DEPENDS:=+libpcap
endef

define Package/reaver/description
  Reaver has been designed to be a robust and practical attack against Wi-Fi
  Protected Setup (WPS) registrar PINs in order to recover WPA/WPA2
  passphrases. It has been tested against a wide variety of access points and
  WPS implementations.

  This is reaver-wps-fork-t6x, a community forked version, which has included
  various bug fixes and additional attack method (the offline Pixie Dust
  attack).
endef

define Package/reaver/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/src/{reaver,wash} $(1)/usr/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,reaver))
```

Comment: This is not a makefile question.  This is a question about how to use a specific build environment.  The answers to your questions are contained in the build files `rules.mk`, which someone has created (it's not part of standard make).  Maybe ask on the LEDE/OpenWrt mailing lists to find out how their build environment works.  But if it uses makefile norms and standard practices you can set `CFLAGS = ...flags...` (note, you should _NOT_ include quotes in make variables except in special situations!)

Comment: My bad sorry, did not find an answer on google

Answer (score 1):

Ok if anyone else need it

"Advanced configuration"->"Target Options" and that change

```
-Os -pipe -mno-branch-likely -mips32r2 -mtune=24kc
```

to

```
-O0 -g3 -pipe -mno-branch-likely -mips32r2 -mtune=24kc
```